# String substitution in Python 3?

Tags: python-3.x

I'm trying to do something like this:

```
subs = 'world'
"Hello {[subs]}"
```

in Python 3.

I can't quite figure out the syntax (having come from Ruby/PHP). Am I missing something? The % operator in the docs I think is Python 2.x deprecated.

Comment: `subs = 'world'` `"Hello {}".format(subs)`

Answer (score 35, accepted):

You have <strike>two</strike> three options for formatting:

- The old python2 style `%` operator that works with C-printf-style format strings
- The new python3 style `format()` method of the string. Because of backporting you can use this option in both python2 and python3.
- The even newer python 3.6+ f-strings that aren't backported to python2: these allow you to specify expressions inside your string literals

## The `%` formatter that accepts C-printf-style format strings:

```
"Hello %s" % subs
"Hello %s%s" % (subs, '.')
my_dict = {'placeholder_name': 'world', 'period': '.'}
"Hello %(placeholder_name)s%(period)s" % my_dict
```

Note that in python the `%s` format specifier accepts any kind of object (integer, class instance, etc) as input and converts it to a string with the `str()` operator that is quite convenient. The same is true about `%r` that calls `repr()` on the substitutable input object. You need other format specifiers like `%f` only if you want to do type (eg.: float) specific format parametrization (like `%.5f`).

## The `format()` method:

```
"Hello {}".format(subs)
"Hello {placeholder_name}".format(placeholder_name=subs)
```

Of course `placeholder_name` could also be `subs`, I just used a different name to clarify things. The following would work just like the above solution:

```
"Hello {subs}".format(subs=subs)
```

In python positional arguments can also be passed to a function call from a list or tuple, and keyword arguments can also be passed from a dictionary if you want to exploit more dynamic features of the language:

```
my_tuple = ('world', '.')
"Hello {}{}".format(*my_tuple)
my_dict = {'subs': 'world', 'period': '.'}
"Hello {subs}{period}".format(**my_dict)
```

We could complicate things by parametrizing the format string, check out the docs for the `format()` method for more.

If you have multiple things to substitute then I highly recommend using named placeholders (with the keyword args of `format()`) instead of fiddling with argument indexes because it usually results in easier to read code. If there are multiple things to substitute then it can also reduce the occurrence of bugs.

## The python 3.6+ f-strings:

```py
>>> x=5
>>> y=6
>>> f'woof {x*y} meow'
'woof 30 meow'
```

Comment: @poke Yes, my info is outdated. I update my answer. I'm surprised that they kept the `%` formatting. They probably wanted to remove it to make the language syntax a bit clearer with less constructs but I agree that using the `%` formatting somtimes results in simpler format strings and a lot of developers are more familiar with the C-style formatting.

Comment: Thank you :) (btw. I’m totally with you that `str.format` is the superior way to format strings; I just wanted to point out that percent formatting is not suddenly a bad way to do it)

Comment: history of Python strings in a single answer =)

Answer (score 13):

Like others pointed out already, there are two ways to do string formatting in Python at the moment.

Python 3.6 will introduce a third option. Details can be found here:

[PEP 0498 -- Literal String Interpolation](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0498/)

```
>>> name = 'Fred' 
>>> f'He said his name is {name!r}.'  
"He said his name is 'Fred'."
```

Comment: This answer should be marked as the right one. See [nice explanation](https://realpython.com/python-f-strings/) of f-strings.

Comment: Agreed, this answer is the only one that (originally) addressed the question of string substitution. % and .format are not string substitution.

Answer (score 5):

The % operator will work, the syntax for which is simple:

```
>>> subs = 'world'
>>> 'Hello %s' % subs
'Hello world'
```

The new syntax for string formatting allows for additional options, heres a snippet from the python docs overviewing the basic ways to use the newer str.format() method:

```
>>> '{0}, {1}, {2}'.format('a', 'b', 'c')
'a, b, c'
>>> '{}, {}, {}'.format('a', 'b', 'c')  # 2.7+ only
'a, b, c'
>>> '{2}, {1}, {0}'.format('a', 'b', 'c')
'c, b, a'
>>> '{2}, {1}, {0}'.format(*'abc')      # unpacking argument sequence
'c, b, a'
>>> '{0}{1}{0}'.format('abra', 'cad')   # arguments' indices can be repeated
'abracadabra'
```

So using the newer syntax, a simple resolution to your problem would be:

```
>>> subs = 'world'
>>> 'Hello {}'.format(subs)
'Hello world'
```

Comment: Do the python docs have documentation for each of the different inputs that can be used in the format func? the order of parsing seems a little unintuitive to me at first glance for some of these.

Answer (score 1):

You can use both % and format - non of them is deprecated

```
subs = 'world'

print ("hello %s" % subs)
print ("hello {}".format(subs))
print ("hello {subs}".format(**locals()))
```

enjoY