# How to reference function argument in a string

Tags: python, sql, amazon-redshift

I have a function which is supposed to query a db as follows:

```
def raw_disc(make):
    data_make = pd.DataFrame(disc.queryRedshift(
    """select D.model_slug,
            D.cap_engine_id,
            D.dealership_id,
            D.cash_percentage,
            D.cash_post_discount_amount as cash_post 
        from quotes_site.discounts D join quotes_site.dealerships DLR 
                on D.dealership_id = DLR.id  
        where DLR.archived <> 't' 
                 and DLR.suspended <> 't', 
                -> and DLR.make = "make"
                 group by 1,2,3,4,5"""))
    return data_make
```

Because the query is inside the triple quotes I cannot add a string that is contained in the argument make into clause where `DLR.make = "make"`

As far as I remember in C I would do something like '%s',$d (can't remember exactly) is there a similar way in python

Any suggestions or resources would be highly appreciated

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35974056/string-substitution-in-python-3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what you want looks like this:

```
def raw_disc(make):
    data_make = pd.DataFrame(disc.queryRedshift(
    """select D.model_slug,
            D.cap_engine_id,
            D.dealership_id,
            D.cash_percentage,
            D.cash_post_discount_amount as cash_post 
        from quotes_site.discounts D join quotes_site.dealerships DLR 
                on D.dealership_id = DLR.id  
        where DLR.archived <> 't' 
                 and DLR.suspended <> 't', 
                -> and DLR.make = '{0}'
                 group by 1,2,3,4,5""".format(make)))
    return data_make
```

Answer (score 2):

You've tagged your question amazon-redshift, and your code show you using Pandas. Pandas has built-in ability to read the results of a SQL query (or an entire table) into a dataframe:

http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_sql.html

If you use SQLAlchemy, which works with Redshift, you can then use the params argument of pandas.read_sql and similar methods:

> params : list, tuple or dict, optional, default: None
>
> List of parameters to pass to execute method. The syntax used to pass parameters is database driver dependent. Check your database driver documentation for which of the five syntax styles, described in PEP 249’s paramstyle, is supported. Eg. for psycopg2, uses %(name)s so use params={‘name’ : ‘value’}

Example (assumes you have sqlalchemy and sqlalchemy-redshift packages installed):

```
import pandas as pd
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
engine = create_engine('redshift+psycopg2://user:password@xxx.redshift.amazonaws.com:1234/db')

name = 'test'
key = 10

df = pd.read_sql('''SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE name = %(name)s AND key > %(key)s''',
                      engine,
                      params={'name': name, 'key': key})
```

This avoids the danger of [SQL injection](http://bobby-tables.com/python.html) which you get if you go the route of formatting strings yourself, which others have suggested.