# Format string output to avoid spaces

Tags: python, python-3.x

I need to modify this code to eliminate the space between the `$` and the amount that follows it. This is the current output:

```
Choose a color to paint the wall:
Cost of purchasing red paint: $ 35

Choose a color to paint the wall:
Cost of purchasing blue paint: $ 75
```

This is what I want it to look like:

```
Choose a color to paint the wall:
Cost of purchasing red paint: $35  

Choose a color to paint the wall:
Cost of purchasing blue paint: $75
```

My code is the following:

```
import math

# Dictionary of paint colors and cost per gallon
paintColors = {
   'red': 35,
   'blue': 25,
   'green': 23
}

wallHeight = float(input('Enter wall height (feet):\n'))
wallwidth = float(input('Enter wall width (feet):\n'))
wallArea = float(wallHeight * wallwidth)
print('Wall area:', int(wallArea), 'square feet')

paintNeeded = wallArea / 400
print('Paint needed: %f' % paintNeeded, 'gallons')
cansNeeded = math.ceil(paintNeeded)
print('Cans needed:', cansNeeded,'can(s)\n')

print('Choose a color to paint the wall:')
paintColor = input()

paintcost = {'red':35,'blue':75}
print('Cost of purchasing', paintColor, 'paint: $',  paintcost[paintColor])
```

Comment: Could you update the tags, please? This isn’t Java code. It looks like Python to me, but I’m not sure.

Comment: You can probably find what you want [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/35974056/1707353) or [here](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/inputoutput.html).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [String substitution in Python 3?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35974056/string-substitution-in-python-3)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can also use the `str.format` method

```
print("Cost of purchasing {color} paint: ${cost}".format(color=paintColor,cost=paintcost[paintColor])
```

Or by using the % operator:

```
print("Cost of purchasing %s paint: $%i" % (paintColor,paincost[paintColor])
```

Either way should do the job

Comment: thank you for your assistance !  the format tag helped a lot

Answer (score 0):

replace last line as

```py
print(f'Cost of purchasing {paintColor} paint: ${paintcost[paintColor]}')
```

Comment: thank you this helped just curious as to what the f string is

Comment: https://realpython.com/python-f-strings/#f-strings-a-new-and-improved-way-to-format-strings-in-python